# Detect a dotnet core project from EnvDTE.Project API

Tags: vsix

I try to figure out if the current project (e.g. dte.ActiveSolutionProjects[0]) is a .NET core project.

From the XML of the csproj file it can be told by looking at the project node attributes:

a) Normal .NET

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

b) donet Core:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

But how to get that information from the [Project API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx)?

I could not find hint looking at the MSDN docs (they target Visual Studio 2015) or exploring the API while debugging...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
Project.Kind
```

C# .NET Project:        `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}`

C# dotnet Core Project: `{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}`

Comment: Here is a nice list of most GUIDs: https://www.codeproject.com/reference/720512/list-of-visual-studio-project-type-guids

Comment: This no longer works as of Visual Studio 15.8. `Project.Kind` always returns `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}`. See here for more details: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312523/envdteprojectkind-no-longer-differentiates-between.html

Answer (score 0):

Since August 2018 (VS 15.8) the previously voted answer does not work any more.

@reduckted posted a link to the vs developer community where **David Kean [MSFT]** posted a possible solution:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

internal static bool IsCpsProject(this IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
{
  Requires.NotNull(hierarchy, "hierarchy");
  return hierarchy.IsCapabilityMatch("CPS");
}
```

Comment: @reduckted To keep the topic up to date I copied the relevant information from the developer community. If you would like to add more information, please feel free to edit or extend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for us. A bit more performance hungry and uses the Microsoft.Build package.

```
        private static Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project GetProjectFromGlobalProjectCollection(EnvDTE.Project proj)
        {
            return Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadedProjects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FullPath == proj.FullName);
        }

        private static Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project GetMSBuildProject(EnvDTE.Project proj)
        {
            var project = GetProjectFromGlobalProjectCollection(proj);
            if (project is null)
            {
                return new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(proj.FullName);
            }
            return project;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks whatever a project has Sdk style or not
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="proj"></param>
        /// <returns>true if sdk style</returns>
        public static bool IsSdkStyleProject(EnvDTE.Project proj)
        {
            var msBuildProject = GetMSBuildProject(proj);
            switch (msBuildProject.Xml.Sdk)
            {
                case "Microsoft.NET.Sdk": return true;
                case "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web": return true;
                case "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop": return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        }
```